# Formating string and writing to a file in java

Tags: java

I have some strings which are to be formated and write to a file,

Sample strings,

```
text1
text2
text3
text4
text5
text6
text7
text8
text9
text10
text11
text12
text13
```

The first 10 lines should come in first column and the remaining lines should come in 2nd column.  from 1st column to second column there should be a space of 30

This is what i tried,

```
   File f = new File("sample.txt");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
        pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
        String text;

        for(int i=0; i<15; i++){
                text = "text" + i;

                if(i <= 10){
                    pw.format(text + "\n");
                } else{
                    pw.format("%30s",text + "\n");
                }    
            }
        }
```

I have attached an image of expected output.

[image]

Comment: but your code doesn't do that. It writes the line `11 to 13` below `line 10`

Comment: then what is your **question**?

Answer (score 2):

Your loop needs to go for ten iterations (one per line), not fifteen (one per word). At each iteration, you have to consider two numbers:

- Line number, and
- Line number plus ten

The first number always gets printed; the second number gets printed along with the first only if the second number is fifteen or less:

```
for(int i=0; i != 10 ; i++) {
    String text1 = "text" + i;
    String text2 = "text" + (i+10);
    if(i <= 5){
        pw.format("%s%30s\n",text1, text2);
    } else {
        pw.format(text + "\n");
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        String text1 = "text" + i;
        String text2 = i <= 3 ? "text" + (i + 10) : "";
        System.out.printf("%s%30s\n", text1, text2);
    }
```

output

```
text1                        text11
text2                        text12
text3                        text13
text4                              
text5                              
text6                              
text7                              
text8                              
text9                              
text10
```